# Run prettier from CLI with config in package.json

Tags: command-line-interface, package.json, prettier

I'm trying to run Prettier from CLI defining the config in the package.json file as it's explained in Offical Docs

> Prettier uses cosmiconfig for configuration file support. This means
>   you can configure prettier via (in order of precedence):
>
> A "prettier" key in your package.json file.

Howewer, using the following command and the folling package.json file, I get the shown error:

**Command:**

```
prettier --config package.json ./src/basic-sample.js
```

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "prettier-getting-started",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Prettier - Getting started",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    },
    "keywords": [
        "prettier"
    ],
    "author": "Rafa Romero",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "2.0.4"
    },
    "prettier":{
        "singleQuote": true
      }
}
```

**Result:**

```
[error] Invalid configuration file `src/basic-sample.js`: JSON Error in /Users/rafaromero/prettier-sample/package.json:
[error] LinesAndColumns$1 is not a constructor
```

I would like to note that if a use a *.prettierrc.js* file with the same command it works

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this error while using a .prettierrc.json file, and the problem was that the file was encoded in UTF-16LE, not UTF-8. Saving the file as UTF-8 fixed this for me.

The root cause of this issue was following the documentation that recommended `echo {}> .prettierrc.json` to create the file. On Windows powershell, this creates a UTF-16LE file, not a UTF-8 file.

[More discussion can be found at this github issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8815)

Comment: Thanks, I just opened .prettierrc.json in notepad++ changed the encoding, in encoding menu, to utf-8 and it works!

Comment: I was using Typescript files (tsx & ts) and I thought it need additional configurations for Prettier. But @Luke Miller 's finding helped to solve the issue. Thnkx

Answer (score 3):

According to https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html configuration in package.json has the highest precedence, so you should be able to call:

```
prettier ./src/basic-sample.js
or
prettier --write ./src/basic-sample.js
```

I'm doing this from within an package.json script, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: This should have been a comment on the OP's question since it doesn't answer it. It's a nice point that's worth mentioning; however, it's also worth noting that if you want to import from another prettier config, you'll need to use a `.prettier.js` file. In the following config (`.prettier.js`), I import [Google's TypeScript style guide](https://github.com/google/gts), but override some of their defaults  =>


module.exports = {

  ...require("gts/.prettierrc.json"),

  "bracketSpacing": true,

  "singleQuote": false,

  "arrowParens": "always"

}

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when I was creating an instruction video for Prettier in Windows. As Luke suggested, saving the .prettierrc.json as UTF-8 using notepad++ solved the issue. Rather than using the `echo {}> .prettierrc.json` in the command as suggested in the Prettier documentation, it would be better to just create the file using an editor or notepad if you are using Windows.

[NodeJS Drills - Running prettier and formatting code through the command line](https://youtu.be/OIECz03CfVc?t=154)